# couldn't find javascript file in application.js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I tried to load i18n.js and translations.js in the application.js.erb

However the file i18n.js could be found, but the translations.js could not found.

it shows me this exception `ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'translations.js')`

How could I fix the problem? I've also tried to load ../../public/javascript/translations.js but it didn't work as well.

## public/javascripts

-i18n.js
-translations.js

## pplication.js.erb

```
//= require i18n
//= require i18n.js
//= require translations.js
```

Answer (score 0):

The asset pipeline and `public/` have nothing to do with each other.

If you want to include the files via the asset pipeline, they need to go under `app/assets`, `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets`.

Anything placed in `public/` is not part of the asset pipeline and you'll need to include it via its own `<script src="/i18n.js">` tag.

Comment: Gotcha cuz the is file is generated in the fixed location by other third party tool .therefore I want to load the js file this way